# Canonical way to define shell entrypoints in `Pipenv`?

Tags: python, pipenv

Using `setuptools`, I'm accustomed to being able to define a `setup.py` that provides "console scripts" -- something like:

```
entry_points={
  'console_scripts': [ 'app=app:main']
  }
```

If I now install my project (`python setup.py install`, `pip install -e .`, etc), I can invoke my application on the command line by invoking `./app`. This provides a distribution mechanism for my application, which can now be `pip install`-ed globally from pypi/devpi, whether to a local machine for some sort of utility, or inside a Docker image as part of some kind of application deployment.

I'm now trying to understand `pipenv`. The docs tell me that I should prefer using `pipenv` for application development, and stick with `setuptools` for libraries. That's fine and all, but is there *any* mechanism for a "production" install of my application outside of `pipenv` "scripts"? Or is the assumption that one will, say, `pipenv install --system` and then invoke the interpreter directly on the application entrypoint?

What's the system here?